# Strange: CSS transformated element JS "click through"

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, css

I have a main content in front, a menu absolutely positioned in back and a toggle button which slides the menu in/out (using CSS transformation on main content).

The problem happens on older (2.x) Android browsers (and sometimes somewhere else). When I click the toggle button to close the menu, the click event is "captured" for a while and than it is repeated on the same position as if no transformation were applied on the content. This leads to activating the link in the content, which is undesired.

[Demo is here](http://metacentrum.tbedrich.cz/). Use older Android default browser to see the problem. When you open the menu (the icon in the upper left corner) and then close it by clicking the same icon, the page reloads (as if you clicked the link in upper right corner).

Answer (score 0):

I figured, that my events were bind badly. In case of anyone would have the same problem in future, be careful when binding both: touch events and click events. Touch event was fired first in my case, then the transformation happened followed by the click, which led to "duplicating" the event.